# Online data mining without client side oauth

Tags: twitter, oauth, data-mining

I have a little app that mines data on social networks and returns interesting results (e.g. the latest conversations around a certain topic). However, the front end requires that the users connects with the various services first via oauth, before these services' APIs can be scanned.

I would like this process to be automated on the server, so that a person using the app does not need to auth with Twitter, Fb, Linkedin in etc just to get results from those services. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No.  This is not possible.  The OAuth specification requires a user to first authenticate with the service and then authorize your application to request data on the user's behalf.

Answer (score 0):

For twitter there is a hack: search, search, search! and 'connect' the tweets yourself :-)

This hack works for apps like http://jetwick.com